# Need antivirus for Ubuntu? antivirus recommendations?

Tags: 12.04, antivirus

I researched on possible antivirus for Ubuntu.

But I have not found any antivirus for my distro Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32 - bit .

Really necessary ?

Try installing `ClamAV` , but always crashes

Any recommendation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antivirus should not be needed for Ubuntu. Linux is very secure, and there are very few viruses out there written for it, with most viruses being written for Windows or Mac.

The fact that most basic programs for Ubuntu are available through the default repositories in the Ubuntu Software Center also adds to the security. Programs found here have been verified as safe and have been tested on every version of Ubuntu they can be installed on.

Make sure you stay up-to-date with the Software Center, avoid downloading unknown `.deb`s or tarballs (`tar.gz` usually), stay away from untrusted PPAs, and you should be perfectly fine.

Further reading: http://www.howtogeek.com/135392/htg-explains-why-you-dont-need-an-antivirus-on-linux-and-when-you-do/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.