Should root directory be scanned for viruses?
I am a new Linux user, currently on Ubuntu 20.04. I would like to know should I include root directory when I scan my system with ClamTK antivirus? Or maybe scan the root directory with a different tool? Thanks!

You should not be scanning any directory for virusses. ClamTK is a tool to scan for windows virussignatures.  See the flaw there? If you want to use your Ubuntu to scan files that are then passed over to a windows system fine, go for it. But it will only find false positives in a Linux system.  If you run server (web or file for instance) worry about rootkits. Far more dangerous for us.

Basically - for most Linux users you just don’t need to worry about viruses - have a search online, lots of articles explaining why (eg the origin of Linux is multi-users sharing a mainframe - the system had to protect users from each other, so there are inherent features to prevent software affecting the system without specific privileges). Have a look here for example but many other articles on the web. https://askubuntu.com/questions/709617/need-antivirus-for-ubuntu-antivirus-recommendations
